# Monkey patching angularjs controllers to have instance functions with injectables

Tags: javascript, angular.js

In the spirit of [Google's angular.js Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/angularjs-google-style.html), I set out to define my angularjs controllers as classes, complete with instance functions. I ran into trouble, however, when trying to access injectable services (like $resource) from inside one of those instance functions.

I wanted a way to avoid having to write

```
function MyController ($resource, $location) {
    this.$resource = $resource;
    this.$location = $location;
    ...
}
```

in every controller constructor.

What I ended up with is  [This hack](http://jsfiddle.net/083fzx34/). The fiddle demonstrates how two separate instances of `MyController` can access the injectable service `$window` and invoke `this.$window.console.log()` from the instance function `MyController.prototype.inc()`, triggered by clicking a button.
`$window` is automatically available as an object member `this.$window` without having to explicitly assign it in the constructor.

The mechanism is a sort of set-and-forget hack, monkey-patching some built-in angularjs functions.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to improve it, and also if you think using this pattern ("controllers-as-classes-with-instance-functions") is in fact any better than the usual "put-all-the-logic-in-the-constructor" approach.

This is the code:

```
/**
 * "decoject" = "decorate" + "inject"
 * decorate the global "angular" object with a new function
 * which receives a controller constructor function, along
 * with its injectable dependencies, and decorates the controller's
 * prototype with those injectable dependencies, so that they
 * will be available to the controller's instance functions.
 */
angular.decoject = function (ctl, deps) {
    if (ctl.prototype.decojected) {
        return;
    }

    var decorations = {'decojected': true};

    var injs = _.zip (angular.injector ().annotate (ctl), deps);
    //  injs is now an array of key-value sub-arrays, of the form
    //  [ ['$scope', $scope], ['$location', $location], ... ]
    injs.forEach (function (inj) {
        //  Add each injectable to decorations object
        var name = inj[0];
        var obj = inj[1];
        if (ctl.prototype[name] === undefined) {
            decorations[name] = obj;  
        }
    });
    angular.extend (ctl.prototype, decorations);
}

/**
 * Monkey patch "angular.module()", in order to
 * monkey patch "angular.module ().controller()", in order to
 * monkey patch controller constructor functions
 * so that they invoke "angular.decoject()" on controller instantiation.
 */
angular.origModule = angular.module;
angular.module = function () {
    var mod = angular.origModule.apply (this, arguments);
    if (!mod.origController) {
        // monkey patch "module()" function
        mod.origController = mod.controller;
        mod.controller = function () { // monkey patch "controller()" function
            var name = arguments[0];
            var ctor = arguments[1];

            // wrap the original constructor with our own.
            // method adopted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101508/how-do-i-wrap-a-constructor
            function CtorWrapper () {
                angular.decoject (CtorWrapper, arguments);
                ctor.apply (this, arguments);
            }

            CtorWrapper.prototype = Object.create (ctor.prototype);

            // annotate our wrapper, so that injector know to pass required injectables
            CtorWrapper['$inject'] = angular.injector ().annotate (ctor);

            return this.origController (name, CtorWrapper);
        };
    }
    return mod;
};


angular.module ('myapp', [])
.controller ('MyController', (function () {
    // Use IIFE to define controllers with instance functions.
    // Idea adopted from http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2421-creating-angularjs-controllers-with-instance-methods.htm
    function MyController ($scope, $window) {
        $scope.ctrl = this;
        this.val = 0;
    }

    MyController.prototype.inc = function () {
        // demonstrate use of instance function in controller
        // with injectable "$window" on "this"
        this.val++;
        this.$window.console.log ('got here: ' + this.val);
    }

    return MyController;
})());
```

Comment: Sounds like you could use inheritance here, rather than redefining a core framework method. It could make upgrading AngularJS in the future a real pain.

Comment: Trouble with upgrades is indeed once of my fears. However, it sounds like upgrading to angular2.0 is going to be a pain whatever I do. Also, angularjs already provides mechanisms to decorate framework objects.

Comment: How would you implement a solution using inheritance without requiring special code on each controller definition?

Comment: You can't, no matter which language you happen to be using. This is a case where "Don't Repeat Yourself" is superseded by the need to not rewrite a framework, which incurs more maintenance headaches than a few lines of repeated code. Just call `MyBaseController.call(this, $resource, $location);` in each of your controller constructor functions. Use `FooController.prototype = Object.create(MyBaseController.prototype)` to set up the inheritance chain.

Comment: I added my previous comment plus a code example as an answer.

Comment: I feel like you *should* avoid doing this because it muddies intent; However if you feel like you *want* to do this, you definitely should not monkey patch and instead utilize inheritance. Also, remember to use explicit DI for minification (`['$resource','$location$', function($resource, $location) {}]`) or have a grunt task to do this.

Comment: Assuming different controllers have different dependencies, that would mean multiple inheritance chains. I've worked before on  systems with complex inheritance structures.  Maintainability was not one of their hallmarks. I think changing a framework is not inherently a bad idea, if it's done correctly, without removing or modifying its internal logic. I'm not changing, or removing functionality, just adding my own logic on top of it. I have no doubt it will incur a price. One of the things I'm trying to ascertain is whether the end result is worth it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I wrote a blog post covering monkey patching angular in production. It gives a quick and dirty overview of how to monkey patch failing calls and diagnose problems that only occur in production. You can view it here: www.robertbalicki.com/blog/debugging-monkey-patching-angular-apps-in-production-with-injector

Answer (score 3):

I took to heart your recommendation about staying away from native angular.js code. I didn't use inheritance, though. What I eventually did is create an angular service function which is invoked from inside the controller constructor function.
The code looks like this:

```
angular.module ('myServicesModule')
.factory ('injecorate', function ($injector) {

    function _attachScope (ctl, scope) {
        if (scope) {
            ctl.$scope = scope;
        }
    }

    function _attachServices (ctl, deps) {
        if (ctl.injecorated) {
            return;
        }

        var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf (ctl);
        var depNames = _.isArray (ctl.$inject) ? 
                         ctl.$inject :
                         $injector.annotate (proto.constructor);

        var services = _.object (depNames, deps);
        services = _.omit (services, '$scope');
        _.defaults (proto, services);
        proto.injecorated = true;
    }

    /**
     * "injecorate" = "inject and decorate"
     * this function receives a controller instance, along
     * with its injectable dependencies, and its `$scope` object, and decorates the controller's
     * prototype with those injectable dependencies, so that they
     * will be accessible to the controller's instance functions as, e.g. `this.$location`.
     * @param {function} ctl controller constructor function
     * @param {arguments} deps the controller's arguments, as passed by the $injector service.
     * @param {$scope} scope This controller instances's `$scope` object, as injected into the constructor.
     */
    return function (ctl, deps, scope) {
        _attachScope (ctl, scope);
        _attachServices (ctl, deps);
    };
});
```

Usage would look like:

```
angular.module ('myModule')
.controller ('MyController', (function () {
    /*@ngInject*/
    function MyController ($scope, $state, $http, injecorate) {
        injecorate (this, arguments, scope);
    }

    MyController.prototype.myFunction () {
        // access injectables using e.g. "this.$scope"
    }

    return MyController;
}()));
```

using `/*@ngInject*/` instructs ng-annotate to annotate the controller prior to minification.

Answer (score 1):

You must strike a balance between "Don't Repeat Yourself" and rewriting a part of a third party framework. Monkey patching AngularJS can (and probably will) make upgrading the framework in the future much harder. Instead, this is a valid use case for inheritance:

```
function BaseController($resource, $location) {
    this.$resource = $resource;
    this.$location = $location;
}

function MyController($resource, $location) {
    BaseController.call(this, $resource, $location);

    // ...
}

MyController.prototype = Object.create(BaseController.prototype);

MyController.prototype.constructor = MyController;
MyController.prototype.foo = function() {
    this.$resource...
};
```

While every controller constructor will need to accept the `$resource` and `$location` arguments, the setting of those values are at least centralized in the `BaseController` constructor, which is what you want.

You have common dependencies across your application, and as far as I know, AngularJS only performs constructor injection. It would be nice if they could do property or setter injection as well, which would clean up your constructor code.